# Let $~k, ~l ∈ ℝ~$ be s.t. every solution of the given ODE satisfies $~\lim_{→∞}() = 0~.$ Then which option/s is/are true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Question:** Let $~k, ~l ∈ ℝ~$ be such that every solution of $$\dfrac{^2}{^2} + 2\dfrac{}{}+  = 0$$ satisfies $~\lim_{→∞}() = 0~.$ Then
>
> $1.~~  \, 3^2 +  < 0  ~~\text { and } ~~ > 0 \\ 2.~~ \, ^2 +  > 0 ~~~~ \text { and } ~~ < 0 \\3.~~  \, ^2 −  ≤ 0  ~~~~ \text { and } ~~ > 0 \\ 4. ~~\, ^2 −  > 0, ~~~ > 0 ~~\text { and }~~  > 0$

**My thought:** Clearly every solution of the given differential equation is of the form $~y(x)=Ae^{\lambda_1 x}+Be^{\lambda_2 x}~,$ where $A, B$ are constants and $~\lambda_1~$ and $~\lambda_2~$ are solution of the auxiliary equation $~m^2+2km+l=0~.$  
Also since $~\lim_{→∞}() = 0~,$ so there are three cases,
**Case I:** $~\lambda_1~$ and $~\lambda_2~$ are both negative and the constant $A, B$ take any value.
**Case II:** One of $~\lambda_1~$ and $~\lambda_2~$ is negative and the other is positive then the constant with positive $\lambda_i$ must be zero.
**Case III:** Both $~\lambda_i~$ are positive and then the constant $A, B$ both zero.

Now from here how to proceed the further to get the desired conclusion? Please help.

Comment: You want all roots of $t^2+2kt+l = 0$ to have negative real parts.

Comment: No option is true. Is this the complete wording of the problem?

Comment: @copper.hat case three looks good no ? The dicriminant is negative and $k>0$

Comment: @Aryadeva I believe 3 **or** 4 must hold, but neither is necessarily true, that's why I was asking about the transcription of the problem.

Comment: Yes I agree ...@copper.hat  Case three gives $y=e^{-kx}( c_1 \cos ( ....)+c_2 \sin (....))$ so the limit is zero  since k is positive.

Comment: You can't put conditions on $A$ and $B$. The problem states that you need to find $k$ and $l$ such that the limit is true for **every** solution

Comment: So only Case I is applicable here. Right ? @Andrei

Comment: There is no other additional information about the question given @copper.hat

Comment: Then no option is true for all cases. The answer is 3 or 4 is true.

Comment: You mean to say that in limiting case Option 3 & 4 are true only. Right ?

Comment: You also have the case where the discriminant is negative but $k>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your equation, the characteristic equation is $$m^2+2km+l=0$$
with solutions $$\lambda_{1,2}=-k\pm\sqrt{k^2-l}$$
You get two real solutions if $k^2-l\ge 0$. If you want both of them to be negative, the largest of them should be negative:
$$-k+\sqrt{k^2-l}<0$$
This means $k>0$ and $k^2-l<k^2$, meaning $l>0$. So for two negative real solutions for $\lambda$ you get answer 4.

But there is another option. You can have complex solutions. If $k^2-l<0$, then $$\lambda_{1,2}=-k\pm i\sqrt{|k^2-l|}$$
The solutions for the differential equations are then $$y=e^{-k}(A\sin\sqrt{|k^2-l|}x+B\cos \sqrt{|k^2-l|}x)$$
This go to zero is the exponential part go to zero. So $k^2-l<0$ and $k>0$. This is answer option 3.

Therefore the solution to your problem is: either 3 or 4 verify the conditions for the differential equation, but not at the same time.